# How do i add content in an div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How do i change the content of an div on an website that has an id with javascript?

```
<div class="chat-area" id="chat-area">[Changeable]</div>
```

I want to know how i add content where it says "[Changeable]" with javascript so i can run the command through the console.
I'd like if you keep your explainage simple, because im still very new to html/css/javascript ;)

Comment: Are you aware that if you add/change the page content it will only be a temporary change unless you use a server-side langues to apply the new changes to the existing file? Javascript is client-side.

Comment: @NewToJS I'm going to use userscript/greasemonkey to solve that.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to make sure you knew it wouldn't save the content as you change it. I have seen a few questions like this so thought I would make sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In very simple JavaScript terms, you can use:

```
document.getElementById("chat-area").innerHTML = 'New Content';
```

And yes, this would work in GreaseMonkey / UserScripts too!

Comment: Ah thanks this was what i was looking for :)
Edit: I'll mark this answered as soon those 10 minutes are over

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [innerHTML property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to achieve your goal like so:

```
document.getElementById("chat-area").innerHTML = "Your new content here";
```

Comment: Why the downvote? +1 just to even this.

Comment: Isn't this a repetition of the same answer that was posted 3 minutes before this answer was posted?

Comment: It was me who downvoted, but it is okay. `:)`